# What are Docusign APIs required to create and send a NDA pairing agreement document from individual peers?

Tags: docusignapi

i am trying to create a document from a pre-populated template which contains the NDA agreement and two text place holders. So while we send this document to each peers for pairing, the peers name should get filled dynamically from the values in DB and sent to respective parties.

I am not able to get what API's should be used. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

not sure which language you using, but there are examples in the link above for six languages to do just that (create an envelope from a template).

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-use-template

the API you need to use is this:

```
POST ${base_path}/v2/accounts/${account_id}/envelopes
```

Where you provide the templateId (and other information) in the body.

Comment: Hi Inbar Gazit, Thanks for the help. Could you please post the format of body/data for the above post call. For example, if we need to populate two text boxes and a Accept button, what are all the details we need to send.

Comment: you can find all the information here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create

Comment: the JSON for this request is too long for me to post here